# how to monitor network activity in a NIC level in linux

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using SUSE. I'd like to find a command to show dynamic statistics of  level two device, which means vlanx, ethx in terms of number of packets received and send.

Comment: Unless the Linux device itself is acting as a VLAN switch or the VLANs are routed down the trunk from the uplink, VLAN encapsulation data is stripped off before it is sent down the link so you won't see it on the node.

Answer (score 1):

`ntop` will do the job for you. In a typical scenario you have to install ntop from repo.

In a debian environment,

`sudo apt-get install ntop`

to get status,

`ntop -A`

[resource](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-install-ntop-network-traffic-monitoring-software/)

Answer (score 0):

Another nice program is **iptraf**. In SUSE you can install it using command **yast -i iptraf** or use your graphical package manager. It is ncurses based pseudo graphical program i.e. it runs in terminal window. Its use is very straightforward.

Comment: Can you maybe explain how to get it, what it does, how to use it?